# Cannot install Colorls on MacOS

Tags: ruby, macos

I'm trying to install Colorls on two separate MacBooks here (one Big Sur and the other one Monterey) but if I run:

```
sudo gem install colorls
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing colorls:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I tried several different solutions but still no chance.
Any help?

Comment: `gem install colorls` works for me on Big Sur (`macOS 11.6 (20G165)`). Please share the other relevant parts of the error message, particularly the build errors.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to install all the developer tools (such as clang, make and libc) which are usually dependencies of native gems.

```sh
xcode-select --install
```